# The Stardew Valley Joja run : What is a good strategy to optimise the cash early game so that run is done as fast as possible?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm picking up the last few achievements in Stardew Valley, and I'm getting to the one I dread. The Joja run.

I've often heard that doing this run is really sad because, well, instead of building up and fixing stardew valley, you are destroying it.

So I want to make it as short as possible. What are some good strategies to make the 140k G as soon as possible so the run is as short as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, by update or because I'm playing multiplayer, PausePause's plan did not work. But the bases are there.

1. Start your farm and give yourself a name with the item glitch. I
   personnally didn't like the Stardrops, because as soon as you go
   over them in inventory, it uses them. So I went with 3 5,000G items.
2. Go talk around the town. Pierre, Caroline and Marnie refer you by
   name in their first talk, so its gonna give you 45k right there.
3. Mine stone and wood. Build a coop ASAP.
4. In multiplayer, have one player go buy chickens, with the items
   glitch, and the other stay in the coop and sell as soon as the
   chicken appears. (In solo, I guess do it by batches.)
5. When that is done (we got 250k in a day) then you have your 140k
   for the projects. Go talk with the Joja Guy.
6. The membership card and upgrades can only be done 1 per day. BUT,
   in multiplayer, if the upgrade menu is open for 2 or more players,
   they can each select an improvement and it will be done (so you can
   do 2-3-4 upgrades in the same day.)
7. When all upgrades are done, go to joja mart, get the cutscene and
   the achievement.

We were done Year 1 Spring 10th.

Answer (score 2):

Name your character **[434]** and repeatedly speak with Gus in the bar during your first day in the valley. The game handles these codes as items, and any time the code is read the item is placed in your inventory. Gus says your name every time you speak with him during the first day. So each time you speak with him the game will give you the item with the code **[434]**
(which is the Stardrop, valued at $7,777).

If you miss this opportunity, you can use this technique to name a farm animal (once you're able to acquire farm animals) and reap the rewards in the same manner.

Other viable [Object Ids](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Modding:Object_data) would be **[163]**, **[166]**, **[279]**, **[439]**, **[896]**, **[900]**, the codes for the Legend, Treasure Chest, Magic Rock Candy, Purple Slime Egg, Galaxy Soul or Legend II, all those sell for $5000. You can give your  character more than 1 object id as a name, and get more than 1 object at a time while talking, so combine them.

This glitch has been patched out of the console version of the game, but if you're playing on PC this should still work. You can read more about the exploit [here](https://www.gamesradar.com/stardew-valley-cheats/)

Comment: so basically, you can make 17777$ (assuming you only can take 3 items with the names, like for animals) per talk, so you need what, 8-9 talks and you are good? Sell everything, and day 2 boom you buy everything from Joja.

Comment: Pretty much, or you could take the same item three times, or you could repeat the item code as many times as the name character limit permits. But yeah, this should be pretty doable regardless

Comment: Yeah, I guess its still useful because my joja run would be done by the end of the first week of spring. And most of those days will be 'Wake up, walk into Joja, get an upgrade, go back to sleep at 10AM'

Comment: Using a glitch/cheat doesn't really seem in the spirit of things

Comment: idk if this is because I'm playing it in MP, but gus doesnt refer to me by name. But first talk with Pierre, his wife and marnie does call me by name